# Angular $resource POST request query params not detected by AWS API Gateway?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, aws-api-gateway

I'm testing out AWS's API Gateway and I can't get it to read a query string parameter included in POST requests from Angular.

However, AWS's API Gateway DOES detect the query string param when I use cURL, so this must be an Angular issue.  Am I missing a Header or something?

FYI, I have set up template mapping correctly on the API Gateway, so that is not the issue.

```
https://cabvt12afasf4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/resource?access_token=1234112313123

resourceCreate: {
        method: 'POST',
        isArray: false,
        params: {
            access_token: access_token
        },
        url: 'https://cabvtj3br4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/resource'
    },
```

Comment: Its not the Angular issue, you can verify the request in network tab of chrome console

Comment: I have been looking in the network tab and the request does appear to look normal.  But, it is not being detected by AWS's API Gateway, while it IS detected in CURL requests and in the testing console that AWS's API Gateway offers...

Comment: Try using postman like clients to test whether it accepts its requests

Comment: It also works in Postman.  The problem is specific to Angular.

Comment: I think this problem is really in the `API Gateway` request/response processing settings. They are pretty strict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was this:

Angular sets the Content-Type header to `application/json;charset=UTF-8` and this was breaking the AWS API Gateway.

Switching Content-Type to `application/json` in my Angular $resource solved the problem.

```
createResource: {
        method: 'POST',
        isArray: false,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        url: 'http://www.resource.com/create'
}
```

Comment: And if you changed that input header to match yours on the `Integration Request` panel? I had similar problem with encoding the output. I had to add `charset=UTF-8` to the end of `Content-Type` on my output.

Comment: That is also correct.  But I'm worried I'll prevent other people from using the API if they don't append the `charset=UTF-8`.   I'm not sure how common it is...

Comment: Yeah, can you change the Angular settings? It's pretty common that it's not there, I had problems with my API Gateway responses, browser didn't treat the response as UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, that's the original answer.  I'll update it for clarity.